# How to create a receive mail only button for outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am running Outlook 2010 on POP 3

I somehow managed to create a send only button and attached it to the HOME tab. Cannot remember how I did this, however I was never able to create a receive button.

Often, I only want to receive mail and not send any of the mail sitting in my outbox as they are often time dependant for the sending. Therefore using the Send/Receive button is not an option I want to use.

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: It should be possible to create a macro that can send mail and then add a button for it to the required tab, or perhaps someone knows an even easier way...

Comment: do you have a screenshot of the button? There's a `sendall` button